# Is there a better way to do this without the use of the module?

Tags: python, python-3.3

Now, I know there is a module to convert these easily but I wanted to do this just to see if I could do it without using the module. One of my questions is is there a better way to split the strings up into bits of 4.

```
def TH2B():
HexBin =     {"0":"0000","1":"0001","2":"0010","3":"0011","4":"0100","5":"0101","6":"0110","7":"0111","8    ":"1000","9":"1001","A":"1010","B":"1011","C":"1100","D":"1101","E":"1110","F":"1111"}
UserInput = str(input("Type in your hexidecimal code, and use capitals: "))
for each in UserInput:
    print(HexBin[each], end="")

def TB2H():
    n = 0
    BinHex = {"0000":"0","0001":"1","0010":"2","0011":"3","0100":"4","0101":"5","0110":"6","0111":"7","1000":"8","1001":"9","1010":"A","1011":"B","1100":"C","1101":"D","1110":"E","1111":"F"}
    UserInput = str(input("Type in your binary code, must be divisable by 4: "))
    for each in range(int(len(UserInput)/4)):
            print(BinHex[UserInput[(0+n):(4+n)]], end="")
            n +=4

def menu():
    select = int(input("Do you want to (1) go from Hex to Bin or (2) go from Bin to Hex?: "))
    if select == 1:
            TH2B()
    if select == 2:
            TB2H()

def main():
    Run = menu()

main()
```

Comment: what is 'the module' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert binary number, hexadecimal number representation to int using [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> int('ff', 16) # 16: hexadecimal
255
```

Then, use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.format) to convert in to binary, hexadecimal representation.

```
>>> format(255, 'b') # binary
'11111111'
>>> format(255, 'x') # hexadecimal
'ff'
```

Prepend `0n` (n is number) if you want the result to be zero-padded.

```
>>> format(5, '08b')
'00000101'
>>> format(5, '02x')
'05'
```

Comment: you probably want `'08b'` and `'02x'` to pad with zeros every byte.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to your comment.